# Differentiate between tab-separated, space-separated and comma-separated streams

Tags: c#, streamreader

I am using the following code to read a tab-delimited stream.

```
using (StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(path))
{
    string line;
    string[] row;
    while ((line = readFile.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        row = line.Split('\t');
        parsedData.Add(row);
    }
}
```

However, occasionally a user may supply a space-separated or comma-separated file. How do I automatically detect the delimiter instead of having to change `row = line.Split('\t');` to `row = line.Split(' ');` or `row = line.Split(',');`?

Thanks.

Comment: Does your data contain any of the other delimiters if one of the other format is used? I.e. If tab-separated file could it contain **Lastname, FirstName\tAge...** which contains both a space and a comma?

Comment: No. The whole file will have the same delimiter.

Comment: Maybe that wasn't clear sorry. If the file is JUST tab-separated could the content be: **ID\tAge\t15 The Street, London, England\tBloggs, Fred**. So you have tabs separating ID, Age, Address, Name but the Address and Age contain both spaces and commas in their content?

Comment: The form expects only numerical data files. So, no.

Comment: OK, that makes life easier then and you have some good answers below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use to string.Split method to split your data by number of characters

```
var delims = new [] {',', '\t', ' ' };  
var result = line.Split(delims, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Or you can use Regex

```
var result = Regex.Split(line, @"[,\t ]+")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't differentiate between them before hand.

What you *can* do is try to split on all of them:

```
row = line.Split('\t', ' ', ',');
```

This of course assumes that the data between delimiters doesn't contain the delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to define what a separator is and how you detect it. If you say: *"The separator for a file is the first non-quoted whitespace character I encounter on the first line"*, then you can read the first line and determine the separator. You can then pass that to the `.Split()` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
row = line.Split(new char[]{' ', ',', '\t'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```